# Как проверить наличие подключения к интернету на API 21+

Tags: android

Мне нужно узнать есть ли у устройства доступ к интернету и получать уведомления о изменении состояния подключения.
Я видел что есть `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` для реализации уведомлений, но единственный способ его зарегистровать который я нашел это `ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback` добавленный в API24.
Как можно реализовать это для API21+.

### UPADTE

Увидел что `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` можно зарегистрировать при помощи `ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback`, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог настроить `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` и оповещении об изменении состояния сети через `ViewModel`. Ниже код на `Kotlin`.

```
fun Activity.registerCheckerOnline(viewModel: NetworkViewModel) {
    val cm = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val netRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI).build()
    val netHandler = NetworkHandler(viewModel)
    cm.registerNetworkCallback(netRequest,netHandler)
}

class NetworkHandler(val viewModel:NetworkViewModel): 
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
        viewModel.isConnected().postValue(false)
    }

    override fun onUnavailable() {
        viewModel.isConnected().postValue(false)
    }

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
        viewModel.isConnected().postValue(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать broadcast receiver
но он реагирует только на изменение, (и мо-моему при открытии приложения ему приходит состояние(по собственным наблюдениям)), а вот есть у мобильной или вифи реальный инет, там можно пинговать гугл(так это называется?) )

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch (intent.getAction()){
                    case "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" :
                        // connection поменялся, do som job
                        break;

                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

регистрация receiver-a

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

и "отрегистрирация"

```
context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```